# CSS Hover effect for height of nav bar

Tags: html, css

Good day all,
I have created a nav bar with various links, I would like to use the hover effect to have it change color on hover. Problem is that the effect is only around the word not the height of the nav bar to horizontal rules. I would like the hover effect to reach to the horizontal rules.

Here is my code:

```css
ul{
    list-style-type: none;      
}

li{ 
    display:inline;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

#NavBar ul li a{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;    
}

#NavBar ul li a:hover{
 background-color: yellow;
 }
```

```html
<hr>
<nav id="NavBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>History</a></li>
    <li><a>Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a>Techniques</a></li>  
  </ul>       
</nav>
<hr>
```

Comment: You should use `ul {border-style: solid; border-width: 1px 0;}` rather than `hr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: solid silver;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

nav li{ 
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1em;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>Home</a>
    </li><li>
      <a>History</a>
    </li><li>
      <a>Gallery</a>
    </li><li>
      <a>Techniques</a>
    </li>  
  </ul>       
</nav>
```

Comment: This worked great, cheers mate. I will tick it when the time lets me :P

Answer (score 1):

The CSS selector only highlights the words because the `a` is targeted. If you change the `a` with `li` then It highlight the whole area of `li`.

Repalce:

```
#NavBar ul li a:hover{
 background-color: yellow;
 }
```

With:

```
#NavBar ul li:hover{
 background-color: yellow;
 }
```

Comment: I tried this before hand it still has the same effect but due to the padding right it still highlights the word as well as right padding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
li:hover {

background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: I mentioned above the issue with this, do you think I should specify padding on all sides for this effect?

Comment: Awful as clickable area differs from highlighted area.